# libsapjco3.dylib is failing to initialize

Tags: java, macos, jvm, sap-commerce-cloud, dylib

I am using Mac.
I know that I am supposed to copy `libsapjco3.dylib` in `VM\jdkVersion\jre\lib\ext`.
On Mac I can't find this location.
What is the equivalent location on Mac where I can copy this file.

Comment: jre/lib/ext doesn't exist anymore since Java 9. And in general, it was the wrong location to put files anyway. Depending on why you need it, adding its location to the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace one that is coming OOTB, in SAP Commerce 2211 it is placed in ***modules/sap-framework-core/sapcorejco/lib/darwinintel64*** directory, feel free to configure the replacement automatically during a
platform building using the process of customizing.
Just in case, ARM64(mac m1+) specific version of the lib can be downloaded [here](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/jco.html#Download).